# Detection of Server

Tags: php, javascript

Is there a way to have Javascript autodetect wether its server is local(127.0.0.1) or production(http://www.example.com) and set a variable accordingly?

For example in PHP is use this function to do reloads and it works local or production:

```
  public static function reload()
    {
    $uri = 'http://';
    $uri .= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    header('Location: '.$uri);
    }
```

This way I won't have to remember to edit my local_on variable when uploading my script from development to production.

Comment: For what do you need this knowledge in JS?

Comment: Whay exactly would you need to change settings for JS based on the server. There shouldnt be any need to use the scheme and domain... you shoudl just be able to use the pathname. If you actually need the schema and domain then you should really take another look at how you have your js set up.

Comment: JS, HTML images, CSS etc are good with absolute relative paths, i.e. `/images/your-image.jpg`, that's relative to document root. In PHP it's somewhat important when writing headers, but then you have the `$_SERVER` variable as you already mentioned. I don't see any problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no built in ways like the one you mentioned.

You can, however, user a regex for detecting `/localhost/` or `127.0.0.1` on `window.location.host`

```
code_environment = (window.location.host.match(/(localhost|127.0.0.1)/)) ? "development" : "production"
```

That's the direct answer to your question. But you probably need to have a look at build tools for javascript or for your whole web development enterprises, e.g. minifyjs / remove console.log() etc.

Comment: local_on=(window.location.host.match(/(localhost|127.0.0.1)/)) ? "1" : "0";

Comment: local_on = !! window.location.host.match(/(localhost|127.0.0.1)/)

Answer (score 1):

You can query `window.location.host` and see, if it equals `127.0.0.1` or `localhost`.